# Difference between generalized cuban primes and cuban primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have been studying cuban primes and while the official definition of cuban primes contains only two variations, I have also seen a reference to generalized cuban primes, which has a much larger set. I have also seen on only one site a third variation of the equation where the difference between the first and second cubed number is four, instead of one or two, which are the ones included in the official definition, and is a subset of generalized cuban primes (from what I can tell).

What exactly is the difference between generalized cuban primes and cuban primes, other than the equation that defines them? Do generalized cuban primes essentially state that there are more than two variations of the classic definition of cuban primes?

Cuban primes are defined as $\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}$, and generalized cuban primes are defined as "primes of the form $x^2 + xy + y^2$; or primes of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$; or primes $\equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod 3$."

The two officially recognized forms of cuban primes are those where $y=x+1$ and $y=x+2$, and the "unofficial" third form that I have seen one mention of on oeis.org is where $y=x+4$. I have been unable to find any other variations (such as $y=x+5$) even in oeis.org, however if it is applied, $y=x+5$ seems to be a subset of the generalized cuban primes.

Comment: Been doing Number Theory 40 years, never heard of "cuban primes". Might help if you explicitly include all these definitions you write about, together with links to the places where you have seen them.

Comment: I have edited to hopefully clarify, though this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_prime may make things more clear as far as the definition of cuban primes. I have been unable to find any other definition of generalized cuban primes other than the one quoted from oeis.org.

Comment: I am supposed to present 10 yrs worth of work that I have done on this topic to a professor in a few days to determine if my work is publishable, and I need clarification to determine if the generalized cuban prime makes all of my work irrelevant. I am 23, so almost half of my life has been dedicated to this. Any help at all is greatly appreciated so that I know what I am walking into on Wednesday. I have never actually taken a class in number theory, so it is difficult for me to determine based on my lack of knowledge of terminology, ect.

Comment: I didn't even know the work I was doing was classified as number theory until 2 years ago. So I apologize if my writing lacks the elegance I wish I was capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Let's deal with the first paragraph of descriptions. Note that $${x^3-y^3\over x-y}=x^2+xy+y^2$$ so primes of the form ${x^3-y^3\over x-y}$ are the same as primes of the form $x^2+xy+y^2$. Next, note that $$x^2+3y^2=(x+y)^2+(x+y)(y-x)+(y-x)^2$$ and $$\left({y-x\over2}\right)^2+3\left({y+x\over2}\right)^2=x^2+xy+y^2$$ You can use these identities to show that primes of the form $x^2+xy+y^2$ are the same as primes of the form $x^2+3y^2$. Now, it's easy to see that any prime (indeed, any number) of the form $x^2+3y^2$ is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. It's not so easy to see, but it is well-known, that any prime congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$ is of the form $x^2+3y^2$. Thus, all the definitions in the first paragraph of definitions are the same.

Now coming to the next paragraph, I don't know what you mean by "those where $y=x+1$". That phrase by itself doesn't define a set of primes. It doesn't define anything. Maybe you mean primes of the form $x^2+xy+y^2$ where $y=x+1$. Or maybe you mean primes of the form $x^2+3y^2$ where $y=x+1$. But those are two different things. So I don't know whether you mean one of those two things, or something else entirely.

EDIT: Now I've had a look at the Wikipedia link, and I see that it defines a cuban prime to be a prime of the form $(x^3-y^3)/(x-y)$ with $x=y+1$ or $x=y+2$. That is, it's a prime of either the form $3y^2+3y+1$ or $3y^2+6y+4$. Meanwhile, at http://oeis.org/A007645 it says a generalized cuban prime is a prime of the form $(x^3-y^3)/(x-y)$, with no restrictive relation between $x$ and $y$. So this would include the primes $(x^3-y^3)/(x-y)$ with $x=y+4$, and also those with $x=y+5$, and, more generally, for any $k$, those with $x=y+k$ (although if $k$ is a multiple of $3$ then $(x^3-y^3)/(x-y)$ will also be a multiple of $3$, so that case won't be very interesting).

Comment: Within the description provided of cuban primes, where (y^3-x^3)/(y-x), the only two variations given are when y=x+1 and y=x+2. While the two equations are equivalent, the equation for generalized cuban primes produces a singular value that, if we define y as (x+n), no value of n produces that number. Generalized cuban primes seem to allow for all values of n, where cuban primes only allow for n to be defined as 1 or 2 (though, as I had stated, I found one reference where n=4, but only on oeis.org). While the generalized cuban prime includes the note about primes being congruent to 0 or 1

Comment: modulo 3, the definition of a cuban prime does not provide this. While the equations are equivalent algebraically, why is there a defined difference, and have there been any patterns that have emerged from studying it "generically" compared to the original definition? In addition, how is it possible for a prime to be congruent to 0 modulo 3 and still be prime?

Comment: Last question first: $3$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3$, and it still is a prime. I don't understand what you mean by, "While the two equations are equivalent, the equation for generalized cuban primes produces a singular value that, if we define $y$ as $x+n$, no value of $n$ produces that number."

Comment: My apologies that our edits seemed to have lined up timewise, however because of the multiple of three aspect, why is there a case that involves primes congruent to 0 modulo 3  when any number congruent modulo n would not be defined as prime?

Comment: I understand now, thank you. 3 was the only value that the generalized cuban prime produced that was not within the less simplified equation, but now that I take that one case into consideration, I understand why it was included, Thank you.